# Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code. REVERT

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, metamask, etherscan

I keep getting an error when trying to call function "setTokenAddress(address input)"

Here's my contract code:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

library SafeMath {
   
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
        return c;}

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");}

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;}

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {return 0;}
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");
        return c;}

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");}

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;}

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");}

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;}
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

interface Uniswap{
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function addLiquidityETH(address token, uint amountTokenDesired, uint amountTokenMin, uint amountETHMin, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

interface Pool{
    function primary() external view returns (address);
}

contract Poolable{
    
    address payable internal constant _POOLADDRESS = 0xc727faca8bFD4303641668F985D2d19A863dd04A;
 
    function primary() private view returns (address) {
        return Pool(_POOLADDRESS).primary();
    }
    
    modifier onlyPrimary() {
        require(msg.sender == primary(), "Caller is not primary");
        _;
    }
}

contract Staker is Poolable{
    
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    
    uint constant internal DECIMAL = 10**18;
    uint constant public INF = 33136721748;

    uint private _rewardValue = 10**18;
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public  timePooled;
    mapping (address => uint256) private internalTime;
    mapping (address => uint256) private LPTokenBalance;
    mapping (address => uint256) private rewards;
    mapping (address => uint256) private referralEarned;

    address public orbAddress;
    
    address constant public UNIROUTER         = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address constant public FACTORY           = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
    address          public WETHAddress       = Uniswap(UNIROUTER).WETH();
    
    bool private _unchangeable = false;
    bool private _tokenAddressGiven = false;
    
    receive() external payable {
        
       if(msg.sender != UNIROUTER){
           stake(msg.sender, address(0));
       }
    }
    
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }(""); 
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
    
    //If true, no changes can be made
    function unchangeable() public view returns (bool){
        return _unchangeable;
    }
    
    function rewardValue() public view returns (uint){
        return _rewardValue;
    }
    
    
    //THE ONLY ADMIN FUNCTIONS vvvv
    //After this is called, no changes can be made
    function makeUnchangeable() public onlyPrimary{
        _unchangeable = true;
    }
    
    //Can only be called once to set token address
    function setTokenAddress(address input) public onlyPrimary{
        require(!_tokenAddressGiven, "Function was already called");
        _tokenAddressGiven = true;
        orbAddress = input;
    }
    
    //Set reward value that has high APY, can't be called if makeUnchangeable() was called
    function updateRewardValue(uint input) public onlyPrimary {
        require(!unchangeable(), "makeUnchangeable() function was already called");
        _rewardValue = input;
    }
    //THE ONLY ADMIN FUNCTIONS ^^^^
    
  
    function stake(address staker, address payable ref) public payable{
        
        staker = msg.sender;
        
        if(ref != address(0)){
            
            referralEarned[ref] = referralEarned[ref] + ((address(this).balance/10)*DECIMAL)/price();
        }
    
        sendValue(_POOLADDRESS, address(this).balance/2);
        
        address poolAddress = Uniswap(FACTORY).getPair(orbAddress, WETHAddress);
        uint ethAmount = IERC20(WETHAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //Eth in uniswap
        uint tokenAmount = IERC20(orbAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //token in uniswap
        
        uint toMint = (address(this).balance.mul(tokenAmount)).div(ethAmount);
        IERC20(orbAddress).mint(address(this), toMint);
        
        uint poolTokenAmountBefore = IERC20(poolAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        
        uint amountTokenDesired = IERC20(orbAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        IERC20(orbAddress).approve(UNIROUTER, amountTokenDesired ); //allow pool to get tokens
        Uniswap(UNIROUTER).addLiquidityETH{ value: address(this).balance }(orbAddress, amountTokenDesired, 1, 1, address(this), INF);
        
        uint poolTokenAmountAfter = IERC20(poolAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint poolTokenGot = poolTokenAmountAfter.sub(poolTokenAmountBefore);
        
        rewards[staker] = rewards[staker].add(viewRecentRewardTokenAmount(staker));
        timePooled[staker] = now;
        internalTime[staker] = now;
    
        LPTokenBalance[staker] = LPTokenBalance[staker].add(poolTokenGot);
    }

    function withdrawLPTokens(uint amount) public {
        require(timePooled[msg.sender] + 3 days <= now, "It has not been 3 days since you staked yet");
        
        rewards[msg.sender] = rewards[msg.sender].add(viewRecentRewardTokenAmount(msg.sender));
        LPTokenBalance[msg.sender] = LPTokenBalance[msg.sender].sub(amount);
        
        address poolAddress = Uniswap(FACTORY).getPair(orbAddress, WETHAddress);
        IERC20(poolAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        
        internalTime[msg.sender] = now;
    }
    
    function withdrawRewardTokens(uint amount) public {
        require(timePooled[msg.sender] + 3 days <= now, "It has not been 3 days since you staked yet");
        
        rewards[msg.sender] = rewards[msg.sender].add(viewRecentRewardTokenAmount(msg.sender));
        internalTime[msg.sender] = now;
        
        uint removeAmount = ethtimeCalc(amount)/2;
        rewards[msg.sender] = rewards[msg.sender].sub(removeAmount);
       
        IERC20(orbAddress).mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }
    
    function withdrawReferralEarned(uint amount) public{
        require(timePooled[msg.sender] != 0, "You have to stake at least a little bit to withdraw referral rewards");
        require(timePooled[msg.sender] + 3 days <= now, "It has not been 3 days since you staked yet");
        
        referralEarned[msg.sender] = referralEarned[msg.sender].sub(amount);
        IERC20(orbAddress).mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }
    
    function viewRecentRewardTokenAmount(address who) internal view returns (uint){
        return (viewPooledEthAmount(who).mul( now.sub(internalTime[who]) ));
    }
    
    function viewRewardTokenAmount(address who) public view returns (uint){
        return earnCalc( rewards[who].add(viewRecentRewardTokenAmount(who))*2 );
    }
    
    function viewLPTokenAmount(address who) public view returns (uint){
        return LPTokenBalance[who];
    }
    
    function viewPooledEthAmount(address who) public view returns (uint){
      
        address poolAddress = Uniswap(FACTORY).getPair(orbAddress, WETHAddress);
        uint ethAmount = IERC20(WETHAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //Eth in uniswap
        
        return (ethAmount.mul(viewLPTokenAmount(who))).div(IERC20(poolAddress).totalSupply());
    }
    
    function viewPooledTokenAmount(address who) public view returns (uint){
        
        address poolAddress = Uniswap(FACTORY).getPair(orbAddress, WETHAddress);
        uint tokenAmount = IERC20(orbAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //token in uniswap
        
        return (tokenAmount.mul(viewLPTokenAmount(who))).div(IERC20(poolAddress).totalSupply());
    }
    
    function viewReferralEarned(address who) public view returns (uint){
        return referralEarned[who];
    }
    
    function price() public view returns (uint){
        
        address poolAddress = Uniswap(FACTORY).getPair(orbAddress, WETHAddress);
        
        uint ethAmount = IERC20(WETHAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //Eth in uniswap
        uint tokenAmount = IERC20(orbAddress).balanceOf(poolAddress); //token in uniswap
        
        return (DECIMAL.mul(ethAmount)).div(tokenAmount);
    }

    function earnCalc(uint ethTime) public view returns(uint){
        return ( rewardValue().mul(ethTime)  ) / ( 31557600 * DECIMAL );
    }
    
    function ethtimeCalc(uint orb) internal view returns(uint){
        return ( orb.mul(31557600 * DECIMAL) ).div( rewardValue() );
    }
}
```

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35f7fec16313ba149311f2c6b30afaf4f2928c0168c52a14e99b21ac55e7a1b5 is one of the failed transactions I got. Can't understand why the functions can't be called, contract seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

The last steps in the [vmtrace in etherscan](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x35f7fec16313ba149311f2c6b30afaf4f2928c0168c52a14e99b21ac55e7a1b5)

```
[106]   6358    DUP2    5220808 3   1
[107]   6359    DUP7    5220805 3   1
[108]   6360    DUP1    5220802 3   1
[109]   6361    EXTCODESIZE 5220799 700 1
[110]   6362    ISZERO  5220099 3   1
[111]   6363    DUP1    5220096 3   1
[112]   6364    ISZERO  5220093 3   1
[113]   6365    PUSH2   5220090 3   1
[114]   6368    JUMPI   5220087 10  1
[115]   6369    PUSH1   5220077 3   1
[116]   6371    DUP1    5220074 3   1
[117]   6372    *REVERT 5220071 0   1
```

Shows what it appears to be an attempt to make a call. When making a call new solidity version check that an address has code and fails otherwise (using EXTCODESIZE opcode).

Looking at the [contract code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x929a3412251f5fa709f1b42f9203750300e9afcc#code)

```
function setTokenAddress(address input) public onlyPrimary{
    require(!_tokenAddressGiven, "Function was already called");
    _tokenAddressGiven = true;
    orbAddress = input;
}
```

There's no obvious call, but it uses `onlyPrimary` modifier. Looking at `onlyPrimary` code we have

```
contract Poolable{
    
    address payable internal constant _POOLADDRESS = 0xc727faca8bFD4303641668F985D2d19A863dd04A;
 
    function primary() private view returns (address) {
        return Pool(_POOLADDRESS).primary();
    }
    
    modifier onlyPrimary() {
        require(msg.sender == primary(), "Caller is not primary");
        _;
    }
}
```

Now it is very obvious where it can fail: `Pool(_POOLADDRESS).primary()`.  Examining `_POOLADDRESS` it is not a contract so that any call will fail.